# Copying a pointer for bit operations

Tags: c, pointers, c99

I have a function that passes in a struct that and instead of doing bit manipulations on the arr itself I want to create copy. How can I make a copy of an element of an array of unsigned ints to do bit manipulations on?

```
unsigned int * arr = cs->arr; // cs->arr is set as unsigned int * arr;
unsigned int copy;
memcpy(copy,arr[0], sizeof(unsigned int)); // Copy into copy the first element, for now
int i = 0;
while(copy != 0)
{       
    i += copy & 1;
    copy >>= 1;
}
return i;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You already have copied it in 'copy', so what's wrong? you looking for a better way? copy = arr[0];

Comment: Is the question "how do I extend the code I posted to work on all elements of `arr` instead of just the first one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `memcopy`. A simple array access is enough:

```
unsigned int copy = cs->arr[0];
int i = 0;
while(copy != 0)
{        
    i += copy & 1;
    copy >>= 1;
}
return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
copy = arr[0];
```

is all that's needed. `copy` will have the same value as `arr[0]`, but it won't be linked to it in any other way. (i.e. modifying `copy` will not change `arr[0]`.)